# How to enable Facebook Instant Article horizontal swipe?

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

I see many Facebook Instant Article can do **Horizontal swipe**. However, I couldn't find that feature. Is it because I have not publish my articles yet? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried adding related articles within the <footer> tags, but that didn't seem to solve it for me either. I wonder if this an automated thing based on post engagement?

Comment: I'm guessing Facebook automatically generate the articles. If you frequently share your instant article (like at least 4 or 5 in one day), you get more article in your horizontal swipe.

Comment: That would make sense. Is this something you are confirming or is it an assumption? (I'm gonna try this to see if that helps)

Comment: This is just my assumption. I never had chance to publish so many instant article in one day since I don't have enough content.

Comment: Fair enough, thats the same issue with me. However I have published about 4 articles one day, and they didn't link up. I added recommendations and the still didnt link up. But the likes on my page are low, maybe its linked to that also?

Comment: "I added recommendations and the still didnt link up." - Remember that if you put more than 4 article in the footer, Facebook will not automatically generates the article.

"But the likes on my page are low, maybe its linked to that also?" - It could be the reason too, cause so far I only see tag like "Popular in [area]" or "Popular in [your page]" that Facebook automatically generates...

Answer (score 0):

Publish first your article. The most popular instant article post is on the list when you horizontally swipe it.

Comment: Thank you for answering. However I only get 2 or 3 articles only for the swipe. How do other page can have so many articles in their horizontal swipe???

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal swipe will be enabled by Facebook algorithm which is obviously not published.
Meaning you can't really control when or how it's shown.

See the following note taken from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/related-articles):

> Note: Horizontal swipe for more articles is separate from the Related Articles units discussed here. All articles in the horizontal swipe selection are chosen algorithmically. At this time publishers do not have control over the articles in that section.